# How to retrieve required information from my playstore app in java android?

Tags: java, android, google-play

In my app I have seen that users don't really bother to update the app so I want to **encourage** them through a **dialog requesting them** to update the app. The best way possible was to tell them about all the **benefits of updating** the app but I **don't know how to retrieve this information** from the **Google Playstore.**

*Any help would be deeply appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use the Firebase Notification Center.Please follow the following Official documentation to implement in your app..

[Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API to do this in Play at the moment. The way most app developers do this is have their own server where they have information about versions which they require to upgrade, and also can put notifications.

If you haven't done much server side work, maybe check out [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) from Google. It integrates with the Google Play console, and it should be very quick to get something like this running.